# Stack with single characters as elements

Tags: c++, string, stack, printf, scanf

So here is the code to create and print a stack that each of its element is a single char:

```
#define max 100
struct stack
{
int top;
char data[max];
};
void initialize (stack &s)
{
    s.top=0; 
}

void push(stack &s, char x) 
{
    s.data[s.top]=x;
    s.top ++;
}
void create (stack &s, int n) //n is the number of elements
{
    char x;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the char to push in: ");
        scanf(" %c",&x);
        push(s,x);
    }
}
void print (stack s)
{
    int a;
    printf("\nStack:\n");
    for(a=s.top-1;a>=0;a--)
    {
        printf("  %c",s.data[a]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    stack s;
    printf("Enter the number of stack elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    create(s,n);
    print(s);
}
```

Now the problem that i'm having is the above code runs fine, i can create a stack and push single characters into it. But when it prints the elements to the screen, there are always these garbage characters at the end of the result: **@ ' 1**.

For example: if i enter "C o o l !" then it prints "! l o o C @ ' 1"

How can i fix it?

Comment: You better learn to post a minimal complete example. Post your `main()`.

Comment: As @PSkocik states, this is C++ but written in a very C-like fashion.  IOW, it's like C++ from 1998.  Just stop passing references, and you're back in C.  That is, replace `void initialize (stack &s)` with `void initialize(stack *s)` and change `s.top` to `s->top`.  You're not using any C++ features, so there's no point in using references.

Comment: You're mostly doing it fine except the code isn't C and your `print`  function should be guarding against the case where the stack is empty. You should retag it C++ (or rewrite it to C) and post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproducibly demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Can't compile. `‘full’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: If the `full` function does not matter, you should remove it completely before posting. Also, make sure that the problem is still there.

Comment: Thank everyone for your comments. I tried my best to keep the relevant functions only. I'll be more careful the next time i make a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code after adding `initialize(s);` before `create(s,n);` and it works.

Before that I had segmentation faults.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing your stack.
Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    stack s;
    printf("Enter the number of stack elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    initialize(s);
    create(s,n);
    print(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't call `initialize()` before `create()`, which means that `stack.top` is *uninitialized*, which invokes Undefined Behavior when accessed.

Change your main function to this:

```
stack s;
initialize(s);
...
create(s,n);
```